# Project Euler 22 Python | 300k from right result

Tags: python, list

I'm working on Problem 22 from Project Euler.

*Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.
For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
What is the total of all the name scores in the file?*

My Code below works for the COLIN example and also I tried with a small list of 5 names and it was correct. But here my result is 870873746 and it should be 871198282. So ~324k are missing.
I edited the names.txt file. Each Name is in one line and without "".

```
nameList = []
letterDict = {"A" : 1, "B" : 2, "C" : 3, "D" : 4, "E" : 5, "F" : 6, "G" : 7, "H" : 8, "I" : 9, "J" : 10, "K" : 11, "L" : 12, "M" : 13, "N" : 14, "O" : 15, "P": 16, "Q" : 17, "R" : 18, "S" : 19, "T" : 20, "U" : 21, "V" : 22, "W" : 23, "X" : 24, "Y" : 25, "Z" : 26}
a = 0
namescoresum = 0
b = 0
c = 0
while a < 5163:
    x = raw_input()
    nameList.append(x)
    a += 1

nameList.sort()
print nameList

for name in nameList:
    b += 1
    lettersum = 0
    for letter in name:
        c += 1
        lettersum += letterDict[letter]
    indexofname = nameList.index(name)
    namescoresum += (lettersum * indexofname)

print "NAMESCORESUM: ", namescoresum
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an off-by-one error. Remember that array indexes start at zero, but ordinal numbers (like first, second, 938th) start at one.

Try this:

```
namescoresum += lettersum * (indexofname+1)
```

To determine for sure if you have an off-by-one error, add this to your `for` loop:

```
if name == 'COLIN':
    print 'COLIN', indexofname
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to complete this question a little bit... in case you wanted to solve the problem with a single comprehension list (assuming you already have your data ready to go), here's some tips:

- ord, ASCII, sum, enumerate

There you go :-)